# Skaffold Kubernetes does not display React changes

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, nodemon, skaffold

**The issue:**

When running skaffold and update watched files, I see the file sync update occur and nodemon restart the server, but refreshing the page doesn't show the change.  It's not until after I stop skaffold entirely and restart that I see the change.

```
Syncing 1 files for test/dev-client:e9c0a112af09abedcb441j4asdfasfd1cf80f2a9bc80342fd4123f01f32e234cfc18
Watching for changes every 1s...
[client-deployment-656asdf881-m643v client] [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[client-deployment-656asdf881-m643v client] [nodemon] starting `node bin/server.js`
```

**The setup:**

I have a simple microservices application.  It has a server side (flask/python) and a client side (react) with express handling the dev server.  I have nodemon on with the legacy watch flag as true (For Chokidar polling).   On development I'm using Kubernetes via Docker for Mac.

**Code:**

I'm happy to post my code to assist.  Just let me know which ones are most needed.

Here's some starters:

Skaffold.yaml:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta7
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: test/dev-client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
      sync:
        '**/*.css': .
        '**/*.scss': .
        '**/*.js': .
    - image: test/dev-server
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
      sync:
        '**/*.py': .
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s-test/client-ip-service.yaml
      - k8s-test/client-deployment.yaml
      - k8s-test/ingress-service.yaml
      - k8s-test/server-cluster-ip-service.yaml
      - k8s-test/server-deployment.yaml
```

The relevant part from Package.json:

```
 "start": "nodemon -L bin/server.js",
```

Dockerfile.dev (Client side):

```
# base image
FROM node:10.8.0-alpine

# setting the working directory 
# may have to run this depending on environment
# RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin' to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app depencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install

# copy over everything else
COPY . .

# start the app.
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I was using the wrong pattern for my file syncs.  **/*.js doesn't sync the directory properly.

After changing

```
sync:
        '**/*.css': .
        '**/*.scss': .
        '**/*.js': .
```

to

```
sync:
        '***/*.css': .
        '***/*.scss': .
        '***/*.js': .
```

It immediately began working.

---

Update:
On the latest versions of skaffold, this pattern no longer works as skaffold abandoned flattening by default.  You can now use **/* patterns and get the same results.

Comment: @jtlz2 that's my ticket.  Along with my edit (see above), there is now a new ticket discussing this: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/2158

Comment: I am getting issues with syncing in skaffold run, but since I have little idea where to start the question would be too vague :(

Comment: If you post an issue on github or a question here, let me know and I'd be happy to look over it.

Comment: Thanks @dizzy, much appreciated!